# Tomcat 9.0.16 on OS X: Safari fails to load gzip-compressed content over HTTP/2

Tags: tomcat, safari, compression, gzip, http2

We are running a Tomcat 9.0.16 server on OS X Mojave (10.14.3) with OpenJDK 11.0.1+13 and are in the process of upgrading to HTTP/2. However, using this configuration, Safari cannot load any gzip-compressed content from the server and outputs an error message "The network connection was lost.". This really only happens when loading gzip-compressed contents; switching off compression for the HTTP/2 upgrade protocol (org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol) would solve the problem. No other browsers seem to have this problem (tested successfully on up-to-date Edge, Firefox, and Chrome).

What we already tried:

- Different settings for sendFile -> problem persists
- Different settings for compressionMinSize -> problem persists
- Experimenting with different MIME types in compressibleMimeType -> problem persists
- Using org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol in the connector -> problem persists
- Using org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol in the connector with APR 1.6.5 and tomcat-native 1.2.21 -> problem persists

Right now, our only options are to either use HTTP/2 without compression or downgrade to HTTP/1.1. I noticed there is a similar bug on the Debian apache2 bugtracker: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=915103 . Might be related, as the bug is looks similar and there as well, only Safari is affected.

Does anyone have any hints what the problem might be here? Tomcat bug? Safari bug? JVM bug? Until now, I have not been able to get to the root of this issue and Tomcat's logfiles don't seem to help either.

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: Can you connect over HTTP/2 via curl and show the output?

Comment: Here you go: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" --insecure --http2 --verbose https://localhost:8443/E.json -> Output at https://pastebin.com/pe3201p9 . Note the "curl: (18) transfer closed with 46401 bytes remaining to read" -> That seems strange. Any ideas?

Comment: I should note that when disabling the HTTP/2 UpgradeProtocol in the server.xml, curl does not return above error and everything works just fine with HTTP/1.1. Same for HTTP/2 without gzip compression.

Comment: That curl error does seem odd. There have definitely been problems with sendfile in the past (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50432847/tomcat-8-5-29-http-2-is-not-supporting-gzip-compression)

Comment: The other option is to stick a webserver in front of it like Apache or Nginx and ProxyPass requests back to Tomcat but let the webserver deal with HTTP/2 (and possibly TLS, GZIP...etc). Apache has best HTTP/2 support IMHO. This is my preferred option anyway as think a webserver is better at things like certificate management and security options.

Comment: Well, sendFile is disabled. A webserver could be put in front of Tomcat but our web applications have been working for years on standalone Tomcat without any issues. For now, we'll stick with HTTP/1.1 but hopefully this will be resolved soon. What I do find very odd as well is that how come curl and Safari both lose the connection while Edge, Chrome, and Firefox do not have any problems loading the gzipped content. If anyone has any more input on this issue, please share. Thanks.

Comment: Quick update, as this is still not fixed. For what it's worth, I have tested my webapp in a docker container based on the image tomcat:9.0.16-jre11; used the APR connector and enabled HTTP/2 and GZIP. Webapp was running fine in Chrome; Safari could not open it. When compression is disabled, everything works fine. This is a strong indicator, that OS X is not the issue. I'd still be happy if anyone has any hints as how to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

had the exact same problem (tomcat version was 9.021). Problem was we had useSendfile on false. Default is true - so you can leave it out. It did work before, but then apple changed  something. Verified  that it worked with older MacOS versions (think sierra or so).

> <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol"
> compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,text/javascript,application/javascript,application/json"
> compression="on" compressionMinSize="1024" useSendfile="true"

/>

GZIP and Http2 work now on Ipad  (chrome, safari).